# Chrome type property of custom webpart is not becoming none in the publishing page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using `custom web part` in a `publishing page` of SharePoint 2010 and

I did `chrome type none` by programmatic of that web part. I applied chrome type property none in the .webpart file.

When I put this web part in publishing page, it is not working. It gives the default chrome type, doesn't matter whatever I set in the property.

More ever when I do the chrome type none from the browser, it also doesn't reflect.

Comment: did you checked it with a user having read permission? If not try that out

Answer (score 0):

I dont know it may help you or not but let's give it a try :

Open the site in SPD, go to faulty page, and open the page in the coding mode. Look for the webpart page main property.

Change the ID of the webpart zone  to anything other than its original name .

After that save that page checkin publish and re try to make chrome type one.

Let me if this help you or not.